# How do I combine a piecewise function within a parametric plot?

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I'm trying to combine two functions together piecewise style, but nest that within a `ParametricPlot` function. Here's my code right now:

```
xstrain1 = 1/72 Cos[q] (2 Cos[q/2] + 3 Sin[q])^2;
ystrain1 = 1/72 (3 + Csc[q/2])^2 Sin[q]^3;
xstrain2 = 1/2 Cos[q] Sin[q]^2;
ystrain2 = Sin[q]^3/2;

ParametricPlot[{{xstrain1, ystrain1}, {xstrain2, ystrain2}},
                {q, 0,2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

and this is what it prints out:

[image]

I need to combine the blue line with the orange line at the point of intersection, and I need to use the blue on the range of `{0 < x<point of intersection}` and then the red on the range of `{point of intersection<x<2pi}`. I'm trying to do something with nesting a `ParametricPlot` within a `Piecewise` function, but this may not be the best way to do this.

Comment: Could you provide `{{xstrain1, ystrain1}, {xstrain2, ystrain2}}` - if not the exact form them a similar function that I can plot?

Comment: xstrain1 = 1/72 Cos[[Theta]] (2 Cos[[Theta]/2] + 3 Sin[[Theta]])^2;

ystrain1 = 1/72 (3 + Csc[[Theta]/2])^2 Sin[[Theta]]^3;

xstrain2 = 1/2 Cos[[Theta]] Sin[[Theta]]^2;

ystrain2 = Sin[[Theta]]^3/2;

Comment: always give something we can copy paste, people are lazy here ;).

Answer (score 1):

First thing you have to do is to find the interceptions. You can do that with `NSolve`

```
q0 = q /. NSolve[{xstrain1 == xstrain2, 0.01 < q < 2 Pi}, q]
```

> {0.679674,1.5708,3.14159,4.71239,5.60351}

As you can see you need the first and last point.

```
q1 = q0[[1]]
q2 = q0[[5]]

x[q_] = Piecewise[{{xstrain1,  0 <= q <= q1},
                   {xstrain2, q1 <= q <= q2},
                   {xstrain1, q2 <= q <= 2 Pi}}];
y[q_] = Piecewise[{{ystrain1,  0 <= q <= q1},
                   {ystrain2, q1 <= q <= q2},
                   {ystrain1, q2 <= q <= 2 Pi}}];

ParametricPlot[{{xstrain1, ystrain1}, {xstrain2, ystrain2}, {x[q], y[q]}},
               {q, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, {Green, Dashed}}]
```

[image]